# Chart.js displays dates in x axis that are not present in my dataset

Tags: chart.js

I have a problem with my x-axis in chart.js.

My objective is to display stock prices in a graph. I want my users to be able to toggle multiple timeframes and modify the graph in consequence. For example, by default the graph displays the daily prices (measured from 9:30 to 16:00). If a user wants to see the weekly prices, then the graph changes and display all my data measures from 7 days ago to today.

The problem arises here. Since the weekend I take no measures of the price (the stock market is closed), my x-axis still displays all 7 days (including weekend days). I want to know if there is a way to discriminate against weekends in my x-axis.

Here's a picture of my problem:

[image]

As you can see, October 30th and 31st collapse on top of each other because , while I have no data for them they are still included in my axis.

Here is a copy of my code:

***I receive the data by an ajax call (named 'data')***

```
var min_x = new Date();
var max_x = new Date();
min_x.setDate(min_x.getDate() - 8);
myChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.unitStepSize = 1;
myChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.isoWeekday = true;
myChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.maxTicksLimit = 8;
myChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.unit = 'day';
myChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].distribution = 'timeseries';
myChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.autoSkip = true;

myChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.min = min_x;
myChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.max = max_x;
myChart.update();

    for (var k = 1; k < data.datapoints.length; k++){
      var point = data.datapoints[data.datapoints.length - k].latest_price;
      var date = data.datapoints[data.datapoints.length - k].time;
      label_list.push(date);
      datalist_list.push(data.datapoints[k].latest_price);
      var new_small_dict = {'x':data.datapoints[k].time, 'y':data.datapoints[k].latest_price};
      dictionary_list.push(new_small_dict);
    }
   myChart.data.labels = label_list;
   myChart.data.datasets[0].data = dictionary_list;
   myChart.update();
```

If anybody has an idea on how to solve this issue, that would help me greatly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Really curious about the solution. If you won't be faster, I'll post it here then. Have the same issue with the same task :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it. It was surprisingly easy solution for my issue, I hope it'll be for yours either.

In my answer I am using latest version, of Chart.js 3, but timeseries should be present in older versions as well.

> The time series scale extends from the time scale and supports all the same options. However, for the time series scale, each data point is **spread equidistant**.

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/timeseries.html

I had

```
scales: {       
   x: {        
      type: 'time'
   }
}
```

[image: Weekends had ugly lines with no change in prices]

Then I changed it to **timeseries**:

```
scales: {       
   x: {        
      type: 'timeseries'
   }
}
```

[image: Now it is OK, even if it shows pre market/after hours prices]

And it works now. I just noticed bug with overlapping weekend dates, but that's another issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here is what I did.

Since I am using object data and providing [{x: "", y: ""}...]

I needed to add "source": "data" to the ticks object for the axis with the issue.

```
{
"scales": {
    "x": {
        "ticks": {
            **"source": "data"**
        },
        "time": {
            "displayFormats": {
                "day": "MMM D ddd"
            },
            "unit": "day"
        },
        "type": "timeseries",
        "title": {
            "display": true,
            "text": "Date"
        }
    }
}
```